# Add hpple to Swift project - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue

Tags: ios, swift, hpple

I am adding the hpple files to my Swift project and get the following error message in my XPathQuery.m class at the following import:

```
#import <libxml/tree.h>
```

--> 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
I also get the message: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue.

I have attempted to link the binary with libraries (libxml2.dylib and so on) but don't believe I really need to do that any more in Swift.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Build Settings of the project

- add `$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2` in `Header Search Paths`
- add `-lxml2` in `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: But where can I add Header Search Paths? Cannot find it in the Target Build Settings. I am using XCode version 6.4.

Comment: typing `Header Search Paths` in the search/filter field does not filter and display any result?

Comment: Works now, thanks! Found the Header Search Paths under Build Settings / All